# Algorithm time requirement

Tags: java, algorithm

I believe the order of the below code O(n^3), is this correct?

```
for ( i = 1, sum = 0; i <= N; i++ ) {
   for ( j = 1; j <= i; j++ ) {
      sum++; 
   }
}
```

I understand the outer loop iterates N times. The inner loop iterates i times for each and every i, and since i iterates N times, I assume the inner loop can be said to iterate N^2 times (1 + 2 + ... + N-1 + N = N(N+1)/2 = N^2 in Big Oh). So you get N * N^2 = N^3, or at least I suspect.

My understanding of Big Oh notation is that you want to find the worst case time, because you're looking for the upper bound. That makes sense to me, but when you're actually looking at code like this do you just look for the behavior of the inner loop when i approaches N, or do you look at total behavior? In other words, am I correct for thinking about the inner loop iterating i times for every i <= N, or should I just throw away the series for the inner loop and see that it iterates N times when i = N?

Comment: Stop after "Big Oh)" in your first paragraph and you nailed it.  The N terms in your sum are from the N iterations of the outer loop, so don't multiply the sum by N.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It's O(n<sup>2</sup>). As you correctly note, the inner loop is N and the outer loop is N - together the are N<sup>2</sup>. That being said for N<sup>3</sup> you could add another inner loop,

```
for ( i = 1, sum = 0; i <= N; i++ ) {
  for ( j = 1; j <= i; j++ ) {
    for ( t = 1; t <= j, t++ ) {
      sum++; 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I just misunderstood exactly what you look for when using Big Oh. This has cleared up a lot of the other examples in the book, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You'd actually get O(n^2).

Simplified way: Two loops, each at a multiple of N. Therefore O(n^2).

Normal way: Two loops, looping n and n/2 times respectively. That's n^2/2 which is in O(n^2).

Answer (score 1):

> So you get N * N^2 = N^3, or at least I suspect.

There is no logical basis for multiplying N by N^2.

Complexity is basically about adding up the number of computational steps; i.e. instructions or basic statements that are executed.  So to do it "by the book" you need to:

- analyse each statement to give you the number of times it will be executed,
- add them all up to give you a function on `N`, and finally
- convert that to Big O notation by identifying the term that dominates as N goes to infinity.

Once you get the hang of it, you can take logical short-cuts.  But you need to understand what you are doing ... first ... or else your short-cuts are likely to be invalid.

---

Here's a by-the-book analysis for your example:

- In statement #1, the loop is executed `N - 1` times
- That means that in statement #2, the loop is executed `(N - 1) * N / 2` times
- That means that statement #3 is executed `(N - 1) * N / 2` times.

Add that all up you get something like this (depending on exactly what you count ...)

```
 F(N) = N - 1 + ((N - 1) * N) / 2 + ((N - 1) * N) / 2
      = N - 1 + ((N - 1) * N)
      = N - 1 + N^2 - N
      = N^2 - 1
```

Then we identify the term that dominates ... as `N^2` ... and we get `O(N^2)`.

Note that it doesn't make any difference to the Big O complexity if `F(N)` is `N^2` or `2N^2` ... or if the lower order terms are small or large.  The Big O complexity will be the same.  HOWEVER, it does matter in terms of measurable performance of the algorithm, and that is of great practical importance.